# When should we use ref and out

Tags: c#, asp.net

When should we actually use ref and out.
I know the difference between the two.
Before you can pass a ref parameter, you must assign it to a value.  which is not compulsory in out.

But when should we use ref. ??

I read this, but didnt got, when should I use ref.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 1;

        foo(i);
        Console.Write(i); //i=1;

        Reffoo(ref i);
        Console.Write(i); //i=2;
    }

    static void Reffoo(ref int i)
    {
        i++;
    }

    static void foo(int i)
    {
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: @user2163048: Here in stackoverflow (any stackexchange sites), its a common practice that you Upvote if you find an answer useful.

Comment: Before u told...I did it bro..but it was showing error at that moment..